# How to get the Jenkins created data and time

Tags: java, jenkins

I am trying to get the Jenkins build creation date and time.

I tried to get the information using Jenkins rest Api, even rest API is also not saving any information on the Jenkins job creation.

I tried for plugins to get the information but I did,t get proper plugin to save this information.

Please help me on this issue, thanks in advance.

Yellesh.

Answer (score 1):

The date of creation is pretty straight forward to get using the [jobConfigHistory](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JobConfigHistory+Plugin) plugin and the /jobConfigHistory/api/json endpoint.

Choose the earliest json object (the earliest two are usually noted as "operation": "Changed" for some reason) or choose the json object that has "operation": "Created".

I think that a plugin shouldn't be needed to ascertain the date of creation for a Job, but this method does seem to work.  I've created a [Jenkins Improvement Ticket 28164](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28164) requesting the core provide this detail.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you stumbled upon this: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Timestamper - their doc says "Scripts can read the timestamps from the /timestamps URL of each build". This doesn't help you?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, actually I am trying to get the job created date and time. I have Job in my Jenkins the requirement is to know the exact date and time when the job is created, this plugin will help us to get the build information.